# await a Task and silently stop on cancel or failure

Tags: c#, .net, task

What I would like to write is the following:

```
async void Foo()
{
    var result = await GetMyTask().IgnoreCancelAndFailure();
    ProcessResult(result);
}
```

Instead of:

```
void Foo()
{
    GetMyTask().ContinueWith(task => ProcessResult(task.Result),
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

However I don't know how to implement the method IgnoreCancelAndFailure, which would have the following signature:

```
//On cancel or failure this task should simply stop and never complete.
Task<T> IgnoreCancelAndFailure<T>(this Task<T> task) 
{
     throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```

If possible, how should I implement IgnoreCancelAndFailure?

Comment: What result should the task return in case of cancellation or failure?

Comment: It should not return at all. Continuations of this task should also get the Cancelled/Failure status.

Comment: But the caller expects a return value... you can't just say "don't return anything"

Comment: @KeyboardDrummer I get what you're wanting to do here, but technically it's not possible.  You want that function to cease running if there is a failure, but you can't have a call of one function _cancel_ the running of another function, you would have to build that logic into the calling function.

Comment: @KeyboardDrummer Then you don't need to do *anything*.  You're asking how to create a task that is identical to another task (has the same result if successful, and the same error if it errors, producing the result at the same time).  Just use the original `Task`.

Comment: @KeyboardDrummer: Put another way, if the task cancels or fails, what gets assigned to `result`?

Comment: If the task cancels or fails, the code ProcessResult(result) should not be executed.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like that, but you need to know what you want the method to return in case of failure, since a return value is expected:

```
public static async Task<T> IgnoreCancelAndFailure<T>(this Task<T> task) 
{
     try
     {
         return await task;
     }
     catch
     {
         return ???; // whatever you want to return in this case
     }
}
```

If it's a `Task` with no result, just leave the `catch` empty (or perhaps log the exception... swallowed exceptions make for hard debugging)

If you just want to execute `ProcessResult` only when `GetMyTask` succeeds, you can do this:

```
async void Foo()
{
    try
    {
        var result = await GetMyTask();
        ProcessResult(result);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // handle the exception somehow, or ignore it (not recommended)
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would *strongly* recommend against returning `null` (or "nothing"), it's possible you might introduce a nasty `NullReferenceException` when you attempt additional chaining such as `.ContinueWith()`.

Comment: @KeyboardDrummer, what you're asking is not possible. A method with a non-void return type *must* either return a value or throw an exception.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque yes catching the exception would work. Could you also give you opinion on the answer I posted myself? It solves the question I posted originally, however I'm afraid it's simply 'bad style'.

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to stop your code from continuing expect when killing the thread or process. keep in mind that the await task can be considered a function call that will always have to return a value or throw an exception.
The closest way to shorten your code is creating a wrapper function that uses the ProcessResult method as Action argument.
Something like that:

```
public static async Task IgnoreCancelAndFailure<T>(this Task<T> task, Action<T> resultProcessor) 
{
    task.ContinueWith(t => resultProcessor(t.Result),
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}

async void Foo()
{
    GetMyTask().IgnoreCancelAndFailure(ProcessResult);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the answer. The following seems to do the trick. It uses the awaitable pattern. Could you guys confirm that this isn't evil?

```
class User
{
    async void Foo()
    {
        var result = await GetMyTask().IgnoreCancelAndFailure();
        ProcessResult(result);
    }
}

public static class TaskExtenstions
{
    public static SilentTask<T> IgnoreCancelAndFailure<T>(this Task<T> task)
    {
        return new SilentTask<T>(task);
    }
}

public class SilentTask<T>
{
    private readonly Task<T> _inner;

    public SilentTask(Task<T> inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public SilentAwaiter GetAwaiter()
    {
        return new SilentAwaiter(_inner);
    }

    public class SilentAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        private readonly TaskAwaiter<T> _inner;
        private readonly Task<T> _task;

        public SilentAwaiter(Task<T> task)
        {
            _task = task;
            _inner = task.GetAwaiter();
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get
            {
                return _task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion;
            }
        }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            _inner.OnCompleted(() =>
            {
                if (IsCompleted)
                {
                    continuation();
                }
            });
        }

        public T GetResult()
        {
            return _inner.GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's going to crash when you try to get the result of an awaiter of a task that didn't run to completion, which is exactly what the question is trying to avoid..

Comment: Well yeah but the way C# handles the await pattern is that it won't call GetResult because the continuation is never called, so in the example it doesn't crash.

Comment: If you're never completing it then you're just causing the program to never continue execution when there's an error.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted! It's the same behavior as the following code:

GetMyTask().ContinueWith(task => ProcessResult(task.Result),
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

Comment: That seems way too complicated to me, especially when you can achieve the same thing by simply catching the exception...

Comment: Alright, thank you. The catch is what I'm doing now.